# Spark: convert a CSV to RDD[Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a .csv file, which contains 258 columns in following structure.

```
["label", "index_1", "index_2", ... , "index_257"]
```

Now I wanna transform this .csv file to a RDD[Row]:

```
val data_csv = sc.textFile("~/test.csv")

val rowRDD = data_csv.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row( p(0), p(1).trim, p(2).trim))
```

If I do the transform in this way, I have to write down 258 columns specifically. So I tried:

```
val rowRDD = data_csv.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row( _ => p(_).trim))
```

and

```
val rowRDD = data_csv.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row( x => p(x).trim))
```

But these two also not working and report error:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => p(x$2).trim)
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this transform? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `sqlContext` instead of `sparkContext` as

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .load(("~/test.csv")
```

this will create `dataframe`. calling `.rdd` on `df` should give you `RDD[Row]`

```
val rdd = df.rdd
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but when I run you code it always shows: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.csv.

Comment: same error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class for data source: csv.

Comment: try `val df = sqlContext.read.option("header", true).csv("~/test.csv")` then :) should work for sure

Comment: I have to say thank you very much and I really appreciate your help. This time I got:  error: value csv is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.

Comment: how did you initialized sqlContext? you had to do `val sqlContext = SparkSession.builder().appName("application name").master("local").getOrCreate().sqlContext`

Answer (score 2):

Rather reading as a textFile read CSV files with the [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

In your case

```
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .option("quote", "\"")  //escape the quotes 
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true)  // escape space before your data
    .load("cars.csv")
```

This loads data as a dataframe, now you can easily change it to RDD.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other answers that are correct, the correct way to do what you're trying to do is to use `Row.fromSeq` inside the map function.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array((1 to 258).toArray, (1 to 258).toArray) )
            .map(Row.fromSeq(_))
```

This will turn your `rdd`  to type `Row`:

```
 Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how to do that in my code? I tried   val rowRDD = data_csv.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row.fromSeq(p(_).trim)) but it is not correct.

Comment: you can `trim` before you convert to `Row`.  Something like 
`data_csv.map(_.split(",")).map(x => x.map(_.trim)).map(Row.fromSeq(_))`